# Installing a snippet into Django from http://djangosnippets.org/

Tags: django

How can I install this snippet into my django app?

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1364/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "install" a snippet directly from djangosnippets as it's barely more than a pastebin. You need to copy the snippet content into your project source.

Comment: So I can paste this code into my __init__.py file of the app?

Comment: Yes. You can paste it into any importable Python module you like. Wherever makes the most sense for how you intend to use the snippet in your project.

Comment: Appreciate the help! Thank you!